# expected ')' got '.' !!! How to detect the file with error?

Tags: less

I recently upgraded less to 1.3.3v began to encounter this error

```
 expected ')' got '.'
```

during less to css compilation...

This is the error trace of the

> at error (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:198:15)
>   at expect (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:190:13)
>   at Object. (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:884:25)
>   at $ (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:133:24)
>   at Object.primary (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:527:32)
>   at $ (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:133:24)
>   at Object.block (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:1121:42)
>   at $ (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:133:24)
>   at Object.ruleset (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:1144:54)
>   at $ (/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:133:24)
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/parser.rb:103:in `block in to_css'
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:90:in`block in do_lock'
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:88:in `do_lock'
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:60:in`lock'
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:30:in `exec'
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/java_script.rb:26:in`exec'
>   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/less-2.3.2/lib/less/parser.rb:103:in `to_css'

guess its some syntax error... My question is how to detect the file and the line number of the error ??? I'm not sure how to debug ??? 
Any Suggestions ????

PS : havent encountered this before upgrading

Comment: isn't that the line and character position at the end of the row e.g. 198:15?

Comment: Auh I need to know how to detect the import file in which the error occurs... I cant able to trace out which "less file" has that error

Comment: remove them all one by one until the error disappears?